# How to combine two columns to make one long column when there is no ID var?

Tags: r, data-cleaning, data-wrangling

I have two columns in different data frames (each data frame is only the 1 column, each with 2000 rows) with occupation info.
I just want to stack the two columns into 1 4000 row long column, so I can take percentages and make a bar chart of percentages.

Essentially, I want to take to data frames shaped like this:

```
Occupation1

Lobbyist
Government Employee
Government Employee
Lobbyist
Teacher
Teacher
```

```
Occupation2

Lawyer
Government Employee
Lobbyist
Teacher
Teacher
```

I want this outcome:

```
Occupation

Lobbyist
Government Employee
Government Employee
Lobbyist
Teacher
Teacher
Lawyer
Government Employee
Lobbyist
Teacher
Teacher
```

Comment: Is "Employee" another column? both dfs seems to share this one

Comment: does https://statisticsglobe.com/cbind-and-rbind-vectors-with-different-length-in-r this help somehow?

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `rbind()` to bind the rows, and `setNames()` to change the name of each:

```
rbind(
  setNames(df1, "Occupation"),
  setNames(df2, "Occupation")
)
```

Answer (score 0):

In `base R` just use `unlist`:

```
unlist(c(df1$Occupation1, df2$Occupation2))
 [1] "Lobbyist"            "Government Employee" "Government Employee" "Lobbyist"            "Teacher"             "Teacher"             "Lawyer"             
 [8] "Government Employee" "Lobbyist"            "Teacher"             "Teacher"
```

In `dplyr` use `bind_rows` and align the column names:

```
bind_rows(df1 %>% rename(Occupation = Occupation1), 
          df2 %>% rename(Occupation = Occupation2))
            Occupation
1             Lobbyist
2  Government Employee
3  Government Employee
4             Lobbyist
5              Teacher
6              Teacher
7               Lawyer
8  Government Employee
9             Lobbyist
10             Teacher
11             Teacher
```

Answer (score 0):

```r
data.frame(Occupation = c(df1$Occupation1, df2$Occupation2))
#>             Occupation
#> 1             Lobbyist
#> 2  Government Employee
#> 3  Government Employee
#> 4             Lobbyist
#> 5              Teacher
#> 6              Teacher
#> 7               Lawyer
#> 8  Government Employee
#> 9             Lobbyist
#> 10             Teacher
#> 11             Teacher
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-15 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Occupation1 = c("Lobbyist", "Government Employee", "Government Employee", "Lobbyist", "Teacher", "Teacher")), 
                 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))

df2 <- structure(list(Occupation2 = c("Lawyer", "Government Employee", "Lobbyist", "Teacher", "Teacher")), 
                 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```